# MySQL db not updating from form with php processing

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-insert

Using the code

```
# the data we want to insert
$data = array($first_name, $last_name, $email_from, $telephone, $dateofbirth, $addresslone, $addressltwo, $townnm, $countynm, $typeapp, $issubscribed);
$STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO members (fname, sname, email, phone, dob, addressl1, addressl2, town, county, type, subscribed) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$STH->execute($data);


?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title></title></head><body> commented out during testing -->

Thank you for contacting us  We will be in touch with you very soon.

<!-- </body></html> -->
```

The user is presented with the success message:

> Thank you for contacting us  We will be in touch with you very soon.

There are no php errors recorded.

This is to insert into this database [image: MQL columns]

Error reporting is in the form of the PDO try catch:

```
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Despite it looking as if it is working perfectly, however, the database seems unable to receive updates. :/

Comment: That try/catch won't do much if you don't have [PDO configured to throw exceptions on errors](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your database structure screenshot, `table name is member` and `you used members` into `your insert query`

Comment: Thanks; I went blind. A one character typo... ffs!